# TypeError, которого быть не должно

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
from web3 import Web3, TestRPCProvider
data_end = []
data_balance = []
data_trans = []
#тут должен быть контент и data_start
for i in content:
    a = w3.eth.account.privateKeyToAccount(i).address
    data_start.append(a)
for i in data_start:
    data_balance.append(w3.eth.getBalance(data_start[i]))
    data_trans.append(w3.eth.getTransactionCount(data_start[i]))
```

Вроде всё нормально, data_start выводится как список строк, но в ответ я получаю

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ch.py", line 14, in <module>
    data_balance.append(w3.eth.getBalance(data_start[i]))
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Что не так?

Comment: сообщение об ошибке вроде бы предельно ясно говорит, что в списках в качестве индекса можно использовать только целые числа, а не строки...

Comment: Попробуйте 
    data_balance.append(str(w3.eth.getBalance(data_start[i])))

Answer (score 0):

Так надо:

```
for elem in data_start:
    data_balance.append(w3.eth.getBalance(elem))
    data_trans.append(w3.eth.getTransactionCount(elem))
```

Comment: Если б еще было объяснение, почему надо так, и в чем была ошибка, то был бы полезный ответ. А так пока - не очень.

Comment: Это уже не первый такой вопрос, и не первый вопрос подобного типа от этого юзера. Так что не вижу смысла переутруждаться... Кроме этого, что мешает вам сделать свой ответ?